# Material Design for Bootstrap Angular Stepper not working

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

Expected behavior

Hi i was thinking of working with material for bootstrap and wanted to test it out first so i created a stackblitz and tried to use the Angular stepper. but unfortuntely it doesnt work and keeps giving mdstepper and stepperform error even after all dependencies installed.

Actual behavior

Work without dependencies error.

Resources (screenshots, code snippets etc.)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mdb-stepper-example

Answer (score 2):

A component from angular-bootstrap-md is not imported, so if you import the whole MDBBootstrapModule, it will be working for now, also add the schema `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` as found on the documentation of angular-boostrap-md. Your `app.module.ts` would look like this:

```js
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
import { WavesModule, } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
    WavesModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserModule, 
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mdb-stepper-example-tuew7y?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: what is the importance of adding schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]  ?

Comment: It works but i wanted to import only one specific module from MDB. The MDBBootstrapModule imports all the modules and also the steppers are still not working.

Comment: It might be that the stepper is Pro component which requires a license: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/components/stepper/. You don't need to include all Module, just pick out the ones you need, use the document for reference.

Comment: @SatishPai I think it has something to do with the way attributes inside each component is initialized. Because the attribute in case of angular-bootstrap-md is added after component is created, the schema is included to prevent errors of undefined attributes to be thrown